# Last trade is bought? or sold?

Tags: yahoo-finance

Does anyone know if lasttradesize(lasttradeAmount) is bought or sold?

I'm using yahoo finance API and it has an attribute of lasttradesize, so Im wondering if it means shares were sold or bought?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When there is a trade the shares were both bought and sold. In any trade on the secondary market there has to be both a buyer and a seller for the trade to take place.

So in "lasttradesize" a buyer has bought the shares from a seller.

Comment: There can't be a sale without a purchase, or vice versa.